# How do I pass my Data object to DAO and access all data object properties in Query?

Tags: android, android-room, android-room-relation

I have simple data object that I want to insert into room database but as I am using auto increment on my primary key I am doing it as below

```
@Dao
interface T1Dao {

   @Query("INSERT INTO tbl_t1(data1, data2) VALUES ( :T1.data1, :T1.data2) ")
   fun insert(note: T1): Long

}
```

I have many properties in T1 so I don't want pass them separately if possible.
In above example I am just showing two properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But you can just use @Insert and not to set your primary key field, can't you?

```
@Insert
fun insert(note: T1): Long
```

Let's say you have T1 class:

```
@Entity
data class T1(
   @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
   val id: Int = 0, // This lets you not to set id before inserting 
   val data1: String,
   val data2: String
)
```

Then you can insert:

```
dao.insert(T1(data1 = "data1", data2 = "data2")) // just don't set id
```